# How to find f(2009,2011)?

Tags: functions

$f:\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$

$f(x,y)+z=f(x+z,y+z),$

$f(0,x+y)=f(0,x)+f(0,y),$

then find $f(2009,2011)$.

I came up with $2009=f(2009,2011)-f(0,2)$.

Comment: how did you come up with that?

Comment: I think that $f(x,y)+z = f(x+z,y+z)$.

Comment: @GAVD Do you think that for any particular reason?

Comment: sorry I made a typo. gavd is right

Comment: I downvoted because posting unsolvable problems while creating the impression that they should be solvable is a waste of everyone's time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x, y) = f\left(0+x,(y-x)+x\right) = f(0, y-x) + x = f(0, y) + f(0, -x) + x$.

$f(0, 0+0) = f(0, 0) + f(0, 0)$, so $f(0,0) = 0$.

$f(0, x-x) = f(0, x) + f(0, -x)$, so $f(0, \cdot)$ is odd.

$f(0, a) = f(0, a-1) + f(0, 1)$, so once we have fixed $f(0, 1) = \alpha$, we have fixed $f$ for all integer inputs.

$f(0, 2) = 2 \alpha$; $f(0, 3) = f(0, 2) + \alpha = 3\alpha$, and inductively $f(0, n) = n \alpha$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. By the way, we may then extend to $\mathbb{Q}$ in the usual way, to state that $f(0, p/q) = \alpha p/q$.

Therefore $f(x, y) = \alpha(y-x) + x$, where $\alpha = f(0, 1)$.

As @joriki points out, there is not enough information to derive $\alpha$. Let $f_{\alpha}(x, y) = \alpha(y-x) + x$. Then all $f_{\alpha}$ satisfy the relations above.

Comment: No need for the indirect arguments that the relations don't determine $\alpha$ -- just substitute your $f(x,y)=\alpha(y-x)+x$ into the relations to show that it satisfies them for arbitrary $\alpha$. (+1)

Comment: since $f(0,x+y)=f(0,x)+f(0,y)$ so f is linear. then $ z=f(y+z,x+z)-f(x,y)$  and $z=f(y+z-x,x+z-y)$   . if we do  y+z-x=2009 and x+z-y=2011 then we find z=2010.  is it wrong?

Comment: @St3114 It is wrong, indeed. $f$ is linear only in its second argument.